# Recover libraries deleted from /lib

Tags: data-recovery

I deleted `gtk` from `/lib`, the system `lib`, und an Ubuntu installation.

Is there a way to recover that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Backups? Do you have backups, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is ubuntu, you can reinstall the packages that include the pieces you deleted.  For example,

```
apt install --reinstall libgtk2.0-0
```

You can get a list of edited, damaged and missing files with

```
sudo dpkg -V
```

And you can find out what package a file belongs to with

```
dpkg -S filename...
```

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall libgtk-3-0. This gets it back. However, dpkg -V shows a lot of missing libraries, and i have no clue why..

Comment: Probably removed a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: not sure. dpkg -V this shows a lot of ???? and missing in the /usr/lib and /var/lib. what i deleted is by rm *gtk from /lib...

Comment: Probably a lot of those are edited files that you don't have to worry about.  Also, if you run it without sudo, there will be a lot of things it can't read that will be false positives.  (Fixing answer for that.)